# How do I fix echo $PATH returning an incorrect path?

Tags: bash, directory, path, echo

I have tried using this code in both .bashrc and .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
. /etc/bashrc
fi

export TMPDIR=/tmp
export SUBJECTS_DIR=/mindhive/nklab3/projects/ellison_on_nklab3/zfMRI
```

but when I write echo $SUBJECTS_DIR in the terminal, it returns a completely different filepath.

I have done source .bashrc, source .bash_profile, and restarted my ssh login, but none of these have changed anything, echo just continues giving the wrong directory. I have also tried writing the SUBJECTS_DIR filepath in quotes, writing it with :$SUBJECTS_DIR at the end, and a bunch of other configurations that I've found from looking around on the internet for ages to find what the problem might be, but no way of writing it has changed anything so far either. What do I do?

Comment: Why do you need to `source` the `bashrc` in `/etc`?

Comment: What path do you get after `echo "$SUBJECTS_DIR"`? Something familiar? Do you know where that is set? Perhaps you al also sourcing a `subjects_config` which is changing your export.

Comment: Or try searching differently? What happens when you only use commandline (`export SUBJECTS_DIR=/mindhive/nklab3/projects/ellison_on_nklab3/zfMRI; echo "$SUBJECTS_DIR"`).
What happens after calling `.bashrc` in between: `export SUBJECTS_DIR=/mindhive/nklab3/projects/ellison_on_nklab3/zfMRI; source ~/.bashrc; echo "$SUBJECTS_DIR"`

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/bashrc` is supposed to be `source`'d by `/etc/profile` or autoloaded by `bash` depending on how Bash was built by the distro. I think what you want to do is this; placed in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

export TMPDIR=/tmp
export SUBJECTS_DIR=/mindhive/nklab3/projects/ellison_on_nklab3/zfMRI
```

Read [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Comment: I changed it to [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] and so on, but nothing changed. When I source or restart, echo $SUBJECTS_DIR still returns a different filepath than what I've given in .bash_profile. If it's any clarification this all has to do with an fMRI data analysis software package called Freesurfer. The rest of the .bash_profile loads in a bunch of modules like this:

module () { eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`; }
module purge
module load openmind/freesurfer/6.0.0
module load mit/matlab/2020b

Could something be overriding the filepath I'm giving for SUBJECTS_DIR with a different path?

Comment: @AlyxTanner You can always run `bash -lx` and see how your variables are getting defined.